# How can I print my mock data on the screen?

Tags: redux, jestjs, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I want to write a test on my homepage.

First of all, I created a function called setup and got my provider and routes here.
Then I enter the value in my input and wait for my mock data on the screen, but no product is printed on the screen.

home/index.test.tsx
[image]

home/index.tsx
[image]

It gives an error because there is no product on the screen, so it says I couldn't find it.
[image]

I mocked my api these tests are passing screenshot of my code
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post your code as plain text instead of screenshots

Comment: I'll do that next time do you have any ideas for a solution?